# Non-blocking and blocking assignments don't work as expected

Tags: verilog, simulation, assign

I'm having problems with understanding such a simply looking thing: blocking and non-blocking assignments.

I created a small test bench just to simulate the behavior of this code:

```
module ATest(clk, out);
    input wire clk;
    output reg [7:0] out;
    reg [7:0] A;

    initial begin
        A <= 8'b0;
    end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        A = A + 1;
        out = A;
    end
endmodule
```

After simulation, I got this wave:

[image: What is that red line(8'hxx)?]

I expected the same value under both `A` and `out`, as I assigned values to them sequentially. Why is `out` "don't care" during the first clock?

Then I tried to use non-blocking assignment. I changed a part of my code into:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
        A <= A + 1;
        out <= A;
end
```

And I got this wave:

[image: Why is everything set to "don't care" now?]

I didn't expect anything here, because non-blocking statements are kind of mystery to me. Why is both `A` and `out` set to "don't care"?

Also, I found different names on every page I got to, so please help me out:
Are *blocking and non-blocking* interchangeable with *sequential and concurrent* as terms? Which one is right: *non-blocking statement* or *concurrent statement*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without diving too deep into the simulation cycles used by Verilog Simulators, you can think of non-blocking vs blocking assignment simply as this:

Blocking assignment happens inline at the time the given assignment is executed, so that means if I have a line like `A = A + 1`, that means we take the present value of `A`, add 1 and assign `A` that new value. So, the assignment "blocks" execution until it is done.

Non-blocking assignment (NBA) happens at a time slightly later than while the line is executed. You can think of non-blocking assignments as lines telling the simulator to schedule this assignment for a little bit later (note, later is still with the same simulation time step, so all of this is still happening in simtime t). So, if you have something like `A <= A + 1`, this means take the value of `A` at the time of executing this line, add 1 and schedule `A` to be updated to that value in a little bit, but keep moving on with the lines following that one. So, if the next line after is `out = (A == 1) ? 1 : 0`, this line will execute using the old value of `A`, not the incremented one. Once the simulator finished with the active code, it can move on to perform all the non-blocking assignments. Now, `A` will get the incremented value and all other non-blocking assignments will take effect.

So, to your examples. In case one, we see the delayed effect of NBA. In the `initial` block, `A` is assigned to 0, which means `A` will take on the value of 0 a little bit later (still within sim time 0 remember); ie the assignment is scheduled to take place after all blocking assignments have run (Not strictly true but it works in this case). Also, you have the clock's posedge happen so the `always` block runs. Here, `A` takes on the value `A + 1`, but remember, the assignment of `A` to 0 hasnt happened, so `A` still has its initial value of `8'bx`. so, `A + 1` is also `8'bx`. And since this is a blocking assignment, it happens right away. So, `A` doesnt change from don't care. Continuing on, `out` gets the current value of `A`, which is `8'bx`. So, we get the don't cares on `out`. After these and other blocking assignments are done, now we finish up the NBAs, in this case, `A` to become 0. So, still within sim time 0, `A` becomes 0 and we are done. At the next posedge of the clock, `A` is 0, `out` is don't care and your `always` block runs as expected, incrementing `A` and assignment `out` to the same value.

If you change the `always` block to use NBA (which it should if it is suppose to be a register), things change slightly. The `initial` block still results in a NBA scheduled for `A` to become 0. But now, the `always` block does something different. Now, `A <= A + 1` instead of assigning `A` to don't cares right away, it schedules `A` to become `8'bx` (remember, the right-hand side expression for what value to assign is evaluated inline, so `A + 1` still uses `A` as don't care just as before; whats changed is when `A` takes on this new value) and this is scheduled after `A` to become 0. So, both the NBAs of `A` are set up, but the one telling `A` to be 0 happens first and is wiped out by the later assignment of `A` to `8'bx`. `out` is similarly scheduled to take on `8'bx` but now, `A` never becomes 0. As such, both `A` and `out` get stuck at `8'bx`.

You can look through the Verilog or SystemVerilog LRM's to get a better understanding of sim cycles and what really goes on, but I hope this helps you better understand the difference!

Comment: Best answer regarding NBAs yet!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue come from using a non-blocking assignment in your `initial` block. Use `initial A = 8'b0;` instead.

The casue for this is likely how the two assignments are processed. `=` assignments are done incrementally, with any new values being available to subsequent assignments. Changes made via `<=` assignments are only available once all assignments have been processed.

Because your first edge is at t = 0 (when intial blocks are processed), in the first example `A` is assigned `0`, but that `0` isn't available to `out` until after it is processed. That's while the first cycle looks weird, but everything else is OK. In the second, `A` is assigned both `0` and `A+1`, so the simulator uses the `always` block instead of the `initial`, going with `A+1`, when `A` is still an unknown value. As such, the values for `A` and `out` are never known.

Answer (score 0):

The terms are equivalent. "Blocking" is the same as "sequential" because "blocking" means that the assignment must be done before the simulator moves to the next line (in sequence). "Non-Blocking" means that all the lines may be done at once. As everything with Verilog, it helps to imagine the hardware intended, so you may think of it as "parallel" vs. "serial" sometimes.

Is there a positive clock edge at time 0 in your simulation?

Comment: Yes, there is. Offseting it or changing it to negative edge first helped (?). What about that concurrent code?

Comment: Why does it remain `8'hxx` in my case?